Why is にも used in this sentence instead of just に?
I got this sentence from a manga

私はもう誰の命にも 従うつもりは
ないそれが異三郎であろうとあなた達であろうと

My question is why the author used にも instead of just に in the bolded sentence.
Is it grammatically incorrect?
Is there nuance when the author used にも instead of just に in this sentence?

Mostly a dup of Question word + noun + にも

"誰" needs "も" so you cannot remove "も".
"誰" is combined with にも,でも,からも,も,へも,とも,にでも,とでも to
make exaggerated expressions.

"誰にも会いたくない"="I no longer want to see anybody."
"誰でもいい"="I don't care who would do the thing."
"誰からも連絡がない"="I have no call at all."
"誰も知らない"="I don't know anyone."
"誰へも伝えてない"="I haven't told to anyone."
"誰とも話さない"="I'd talk to no one"
"誰にでも挨拶する"="say hello to everyone"
"誰とでも仲良くする"="be nice to everyone"

All the above sentences are structured as "誰" + x + "も".
When a sentence(not interrogative sentence) has "誰" then "も" should follow.
Thus "私はもう誰の命に従うつもりはない" is gramatically wrong, it sounds awkward.
if you still want to use 誰+に instead of 誰+にも,then you must put も afterward.
"私はもう誰の命に従うつもり「も」ない".
If "彼" is used instead of "誰" then
"私はもう彼の命に従うつもりはない"
is correct as "誰+も" pattern is gone.
